# Mongoose schema type binary data - type casting

Tags: node.js, mongoose, numbers

I'm reading the mongoose docs and saw this line of code:

```
const file2 = new Data({ binData: 72987 }); // {"type":"Buffer","data":[27]}
```

Can someone please explain how they get to [27] from 72987?

Thanks,

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#buffers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm working with mongodb and mongoose had the same question.

What I understood was that when you create a document with a buffer property,
mongoose casts a buffer, and the default javascript buffer is an Int8Array, that is, 1 byte = 0 to 255 (256), [buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html)

So, when you create a buffer object with the number 72987, it is the same as when you create a const data = Buffer.from ([72987]),
that the same as 72987% 256 = 27.

```
console.log(Buffer.from([72987]).toJSON().data);
// output
[27]
```

If you want to create a buffer that fits the size 72987, you would have to create a

```
console.log(new Int32Array([72987]));
// output
Int32Array [72987]
```

therefore, 72987 % (2 ^ 32) = 72987

However, I still don't know how to save data in mongodb with sizes of 32 bits (4 bytes) and retrieve that information in mongoose.
But from what I saw in the mongodb's documentation, it is possible to read the bytes with a different length.
[binary mongodb](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-bson-generated/binary.html)

I hope I helped with something!